# Does insertion to STL map invalidate other existing iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

I used std::map in STL. Can I use iterator after some other element inserted to the map? Is it still valid?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When in doubt as to the semantics of an operation on a container, consult [the documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html):

> Map has the important property that inserting a new element into a `map` does not invalidate iterators that point to existing elements.
>
> Erasing an element from a `map` also does not invalidate any iterators, except, of course, for iterators that actually point to the element that is being erased.

This is taken from the SGI STL documentation.  While this documentation technically does not specify the behavior of the C++ Standard Library containers, the differences are generally insignificant, aside from the parts of the STL that are not part of the C++ Standard Library, of course.

The SGI STL documentation is an indispensable reference, especially if you don't have a copy of the C++ Standard.

Comment: +1, the SGI docs are quite good. The only better source of information --even if harder to read-- is the standard. You can buy your own electronic copy of the standard for around $30, or you can download it from google's codeassist [here](http://openassist.googlecode.com/files/C%2B%2B%20Standard%20-%20ANSI%20ISO%20IEC%2014882%202003.pdf)

Comment: Note that your link to the SGI documentation doesn't (probably hasn't for a long time). I would suggest you remove it.

Answer (score 39):

From standard 23.1.2/8

> The insert members shall not affect
>   the validity of iterators and
>   references to the container, and the
>   erase members shall invalidate only
>   iterators and references to the erased
>   elements.

Comment: This answer covers an important case that the accepted answer misses.  Specifically, `somemap.end()` is an iterator to the container, but it is not an iterator that points to an existing element, which the other answer discusses exclusively.

Answer (score 11):

Inserting into std::map does not invalidate existing iterators.