# std::map concurrency with one inserter thread and one reader thread

Tags: c++

I have a thread (Thread A) which continuously iterates over a map say MapA.

Now there is an other thread (ThreadB) which inserts elements into the MapA.

I dont delete elements from MapA

Will there be any concurrency issue by this operation?

Comment: i am not concerned about the invalid iterator since i loop continuously if i reach end of map i reset iterator to begining.

Comment: You should be concerned. When an iterator is invalid, you will probably never be able to test it against end of map because operators `++` or `--` will do unpredictable things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a distinction between thread safety / concurrency issues and invalidating iterators when inserting new items.

The STL is inherently not thread-safe, so be sure to mutex-lock when doing anything else than just reading from an STL object from multiple threads.

However, inserting into a `std::map` does not invalidate existing iterators (see [Does insertion to STL map invalidate other existing iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343220/does-insertion-to-stl-map-invalidate-other-existing-iterator))

Comment: Thanks sonicwave and Benoit