# What do I do wrong that causes an infinite loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, infinite-loop

So I am using a list of vectors and my code seems to break it so that the for loop does not exit.

Here is the code which works:

```
for(possible_planes_it = possible_planes.begin(); possible_planes_it != possible_planes_end; possible_planes_it++)
{
    if(static_cast<float>(good_matches.size()) >= static_cast<float>((matches.size())*0.8))
    {
        possible_planes_it->push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
    }
    else
    {
        list.push_back(vector<Plane>());
        list.back().push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
    }
}
```

This causes the iterators to break:

```
for(possible_planes_it = possible_planes.begin(); possible_planes_it != possible_planes_end; possible_planes_it++)
{
        if(static_cast<float>(good_matches.size()) >= static_cast<float>((matches.size())*0.8))
        {
        if(possible_planes_it->back().getTimestamp() < count) // Means that there has not been a match found this round
        {
            possible_planes_it->push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
            possible_planes_it->back().setNumberOfGoodMatches(good_matches.size());
        }
        else
        {
            if(possible_planes_it->back().getNumberOfGoodMatches() < good_matches.size())
            {
                possible_planes_it->pop_back(); // If a better match has been found, remove the last vector entry and push the new one
                possible_planes_it->push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
                possible_planes_it->back().setNumberOfGoodMatches(good_matches.size());
            }
            else
            {
                list.push_back(vector<Plane>());
                list.back().push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        list.push_back(vector<Plane>());
        list.back().push_back(Plane(area, *center_it, keypoint, descriptor, count));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I do so horribly wrong :D?

Comment: Haha. Good point. Tagged as for-loop, yet not a single `for` anywhere in the code...

Comment: `Does anyone have an idea what I do so horribly wrong :D?` you forgot the loop.

Comment: Your `static_cast<float>` stinks to high heaven. Shutting up the compiler when you're doing something wrong is likely to get you stuck scratching your head in front of a non-cooperative computer for a few hours. Do yourself a favour and remove the cast, then try to understand and correct the problem.

Comment: you say you have an infinite loop; but also that the second code snippet "causes the iterators to break". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Now with for loops :D. My bad....

Comment: @kuroineko: Well, I am working with opencv. And with that statement I am trying to figure out if 80% of the found matches in the picture are good matches. Whats so fundamentally wrong about it?

Comment: @Pandrei:
With that I mean that the second for loop is not exited. I am stuck in there. While the first snippet exits just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out vector's [pop_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/) and [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) pages, specifically, see iterator validity and notice how your iterators will be invalidated if a relocation occurs.

See also [What is iterator invalidation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904454/what-is-iterator-invalidation)

Comment: OK, thanks for showing me that. So are you saying that if one of the vectors in my list is relocated all the points become invalid? Even the list iterator?!

Comment: Also note that in the first snippet I am not having this error, even though I am pushing data into my vectors. That's the weird part...