# Continuing to iterate through std::map after insertion

Tags: c++, iterator

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343220/does-insertion-to-stl-map-invalidate-other-existing-iterator) question clarified that iterators remain valid after insertion. I'd like to go a bit further and ask for verification that this is expected behavior:

- `std::map` automatically sorts based on key.
- insertion into the map thus automatically places the new element in a sorted location somewhere inside the `map`
- An `iterator++` operation therefore could return a different element after insertion than it would have prior to insertion.

Does this all make sense?

Comment: Sure, if an insertion is done ahead of your iterator you will eventually get to it...

Comment: @K-ballo by "ahead" you mean after the interator?

Comment: _Ahead_: further forward in space; in the line of one's forward motion.

Comment: @K-ballo: Ahead: 2) closer to the beginning.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley indeed that was my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this's true if the new inserted element is after the iterator you are visiting.