# How to use std::list to implement LRU

Tags: c++, list, std, lru

Using a list and a hash-map, we can implement LRU in Java.

[How would you implement an LRU cache in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221525/how-would-you-implement-an-lru-cache-in-java-6)

In C++, does std::list allow us to implement this?

For each element in cache, we need to know its position in the list.
However, after removing a position, does list ensure that the positions (list::iterator) after this one will not be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement LRU using `std::list` and `std::map`.

`std::list` iterators referencing retained elements are unaffected by insertions and erasures of other elements. See this answer: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

The same is true for `std::map`. See this answer: [Does insertion to STL map invalidate other existing iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343220/does-insertion-to-stl-map-invalidate-other-existing-iterator)